# Nuget Installs Packages Of Same Solution Projects

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I have a weird scenario.

Let's say that I'm working on a solution called SOL.
That solution has 3 projects: A, B and C.
Now, project A, uses projects B and C, as Projects References, because all of these 3 projects share the same solution, and all of these projects have nuget packages in order to use them in other solutions.

I have another solution, called SOL2.
That solution has a project, let's call it D.
D uses projects B and C from SOL, as nuget packages, and D has a nuget package of his own.

the problem is, that project A from SOL, uses project D.
When I want to install project D nuget on project A, it automatically installs all project D's dependencies as nuget packages, including B and D, which are on the same solution of A, and it doesn't make any sense.

I know I can use 'Ignore Dependencies' option, but then I might skip needed references which are not on the same solution of A
(Try imagining a case of 100 references and not only 2-3).

Is there any way to prevent nuget from installing only these specific packages of projects that are on the same solution of project A?

I hope the situation is understandable.

Thanks.

Comment: What are the problems you run into by doing this?

packages.config does not really work well in this scenario, since it does not have the concept of duality (project and packages references are the same basically).

Comment: I may be wrong, but i'm not sure that you are correct.
If projects B and C belong to the same solution of A, and A references B and C using nuget , than if I want to change my code of projects B and C, it'll not affect project A because the reference is a specific DLL version and not referenced to bin/debug/projectB.dll.

Comment: I think my comment was worded badly :)
packages.config does not have the concept of duality. 
The concept of duality is that project and package references are treated the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the problem is, that project A from SOL, uses project D. When I want to install project D nuget on project A, it automatically installs all project D's dependencies as nuget packages, including B and D, which are on the same solution of A, and it doesn't make any sense.

I need to point out that if you install the `projectD` nuget to the `projectA`, the nuget dependencies B and C will **replace** the previous project reference `ProjectB` and `projectC` of `projectA`.

If you do not want to replace project reference to nuget reference, you should prevent nuget from installing only these specific packages of projects that are on the same solution of project A. This is what you asked. The only directly way is using `Ignore Dependencies`, but just as you said, it will also ignore **all** dependencies of `projectD`. To resolve this issue, The workaround which I can think of is remove the dependencies `projectB` after create the nuget package `ProjectD`.

You can get the nuget package explorer from windows store and install it:

[image]

Then open nuget package projectD with nuget package explorer, remove the dependencies these specific packages of projects that are on the same solution of project A, like `projectB`:

[image]

In this case, you can prevent nuget from installing only these specific packages of projects that are on the same solution of project A.

Hope this helps.